# Touch on ImageView in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have ListView with items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layerItem"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="55dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/layerImage"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/layerTitle"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="6.0dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

How listen touch to ImageView and get the item number?

private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mLayersListListener
        = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
    //here touch on ImageView or TextView?
}
```

};

Comment: with an onItemClickListener you won't get touch position coordinates and cannot tell if user clicked on image or text

Answer (score 1):

An *ImageButton* might be a better choice than *ImageView*.  Either way:

```
ImageButton mButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.layerImage);
mButton.setTag(new Integer(position));  // position is the item number
mButton.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(View v)
 {
   // handle the image click/touch
   Integer position = (Integer)v.getTag();
 }
});
```

by "get the item number" I assume you mean get the list view position?  Using a tag object is one possible way of passing this information.

**But why not use a setOnItemClickListener() on your list**?  The user could click on image or text, but this handler cleanly passes the position of the list item:

```
ListView mList = ...;
mList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
 {
   // position is the item number
 }
});
```

}

Comment: yes, position :) i update post. see this pls. sorry for english